# Recurrence Relation when initial condition is 0

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, substitution

### Proof of Induction || Iteration method

Hi, I am working on a discrete math problem, and I can't figure out what to do with:

```
T(n) = 3 + T(n/2), T(0) = 0
```

I have tried Plug and Chug method and Induction method, but I can't seem to work it out.

My problem is when I try to make a general formula:

```
T(n) = 3 + T(n/2) => T(n/2) => 3 + T(n^2/2^2)
T(n) = 3 + (3 + T(n^2/2^2))
T(n) = 3 + 3 + T(n^2/2^2) => 3 + T(n^3/2^3)
T(n) = 3 + 3 + (3 + T(n^3/2^3))
T(n) = 3 + 3 + 3 + T(n^3/2^3)
```

So, `g(i) = 3i + T(n^i/2^i)`

Since, `T(0) = 0`. I need to make `n^i/2^i` equal to `0`.

```
n^i/2^i = 0
```

and I'm stuck. I've looked at the answer key, and the answer is:

```
T(n) = 3(⌊log2(n)⌋ + 1)
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

#### Edit

I've tried this on Wolfram but Wolfram couldn't solve it either.

What I really want to ask is how to deal with iteration substitution method (chug and plug method) when the base case is T(0) = 0, or T(0) = 2. Because, like the example above, when I try to make a general formula, where I would need to make `n^i/2^i = 0`, I couldn't get anything out of it.

Comment: Can you please write down the original question as given? I do not see a clear problem statement.

Comment: Your observations are good. This problem is completely ill-posed. Ask your instructor...

Comment: The question just tells me to completely solve the problem as possible. This is an exercise in Doerr's book on Discrete Mathematics.

Edit: I've tried it on wolfram, and wolfram can't solve it either.

Comment: I don't understand: how can the solution contain $\log_2 n$ and initial value be $T(0)=0$. Setting $T(1)=0$ *Mathematica* (same as Wolfram Alpha) gives $3\log_2 n$ as solution